# Is this proof correct? Order of an ordered pair

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that (G,*) and (H, #) are groups, then (GxH, @) is a group. Assume that a∈G and b∈H, o(a)=m and o(b)=k. Determine, with the proof, o((a,b))

Proof: Assume that a∈G and b∈H, |a|=m and |b|=k.

Claim: |(a,b)|= lcm(m,k)

Let |(a,b)|=t

Then (a,b)^t=(e,e), and since a^m=e, b^k=e,  then m|t and k|t implies lcm(m,k)|t

But m|lcm(m,k) and k|lcm(m,k), and (a,b)^(lcm(mk))=(e,e) so t|lcm(m,k).

Thus t=lcm(m,k).

Therefore, |(a,b)|=lcm(m,k)

Is that a correct proof?

Comment: So m|lcm(m,k) and k|lcm(m,k), so t|lcm(m,k). Thus t=lcm(m,k). Is it right?

Comment: That's fine. Deal with the case where $|a|$ is infinite.

Comment: It's given that |a|=m